# your device isn't compatible with this version with LG G3

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I just launched my first app, it is a remote control app,
tested on LG G3 , samsungs and htc devices.
for some reason G3 users can't download the app complaining the google play tells them "your device isn't compatible with this version".
this is my manifest :

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.samko.controlit"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.TRANSMIT_IR"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"
        android:required="false" />
   <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" /> -->

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.consumerir" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.samko.controlit.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.samko.controlit.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: This can be because of `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.consumerir" />`

Are you sure that LG G3 has IR feature? If not, try to use `android:required="false"` parameter as for others.

Comment: OK, tried it, updating in google play now..
Will comment when it is updated

Answer (score 0):

From your manifest file you are using your `targetSdkVersion=21` but you didn't mentioned the `android:maxSdkVersion`

Which could supports up-to

> Android 5.0–5.0.2 Lollipop

But LG G3 has official update support to many Lollipop version. So if the user's LG G3 has any version between **Android 5.1 – 5.1.1** your app will be recognized as incompatible.

The solution is pretty simple, just add `android:maxSdkVersion` to 22

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22"
    android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
```

Comment: **android:targetSdkVersion** doesn't restrict usage of OS version. From documentation: This attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version. What you mean is **android:maxSdkVersion**.

Comment: Thanks for the review. Actually I was trying to mention the exact same thing. I've updated my answer.

Comment: maxSdkVersion sets a maximum sdk version restriction. It would only define more uncompatible devices, original question is about removing the uncompatible error.